# FLot ordered bars too small and long away from each other

Tags: jquery, charts, flot

I have a Flot graph with orderBars plugin.

I have `JSON` data from 2 different years and when I render them together they get too small. When I render each year separated it looks ok.

I have tried to override the width of the bars in the options bu no sucess.

How to fix this?
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8BC4t/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the orderBars plugin is attempting to do is calculate an appropriate *jitter* value to offset the bars from each other.  It looks like it fails miserably given the large javascript millisecond epoch values (it doesn't take into account the large range of data and appears to try and *jitter* them by 1s). So as is often my recommendation with `flot`, skip the plugin and *jitter* the bars yourself.

A year has 3.15569e10 milliseconds; this divided by the number of bars, is the basis for a good `+-` jitter value:

```
var millisInYear = 3.15569e10;
var N = raw2013.length;
var jitter = millisInYear / N;
for (var i = 0; i < N; i++){
    // find the midpoint and jitter around it
    // this way the "middle" bar is over the year tick
    if (i < N/2){
        raw2013[i].data[0][0] = raw2013[i].data[0][0] - (jitter * (N/2 - i));
    }else{
        raw2013[i].data[0][0] = raw2013[i].data[0][0] + (jitter * (i - N/2));
    }
}
```

Here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8BC4t/2/) (excuse me for removing the JSON parsing, but it was easier to think through with the whiskey I'm sipping :)

Comment: Thanks Mark! Happy new year to you ;) I will do as you suggest and post a follow up question about how to also make the bar width take more space so I can click on it. Probably will add this idea to the plugin script myself to avoid doing this nice patch you suggested. Cheers!

Comment: If you want the bars for one year to be more clearly seperated from the bars of another year, you can reduce the jitter e.g. `var jitter = 0.8 * millisInYear / N;` (see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8BC4t/4/))

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the jitter from Mark's answer you can also increase the width of the bars (see this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8BC4t/3/)):

```
var options = {
    bars: {
        show: true,
        barWidth: 500000000
    }
}
```

Here I used a fixed width, but in praxis you should calculate the bar width depending on the plot width and the number of bars in the plot.

Comment: __+1 to you__, thank you. Btw... that was not a small width! I did try `barWidth` option, but I didn't reach those numbers `q(❂‿❂)p` Is barWidth not pixels? why such big number)

Comment: The bar width is in the same unit as your x-values, so it is in milliseconds. The bars have now approximately 6 days width.